How to ensure all implementation of an interface have certain constraints?
I want to do something like this. But I can't use IMyInterface as the generic type for MyField because it is not promised to be unmanaged. Is there any workaround?
public struct Main<T>  where T: unmanaged
{
    MyField<IMyInterface<T>> value;

    public Main( Flag flag)
    {
        switch (flag)
        {
             case Flag.A:
                value = new MyField<A<T>>();
                break;
             ...
        }
    }
}

public struct MyField<T> where T: unmanaged { }

public struct A<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T: unmanaged {...}
public struct B<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T: unmanaged {...}
public struct C<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T: unmanaged {...}
public struct D<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T: unmanaged {...}

public interface IMyInterface<T>  where T: unmanaged
{
    // Some members.
}


Can't you make your generic struct definition as struct MyField<IT, T> where IT: IMyInterface<T> where T: unmanaged?

Why does MyField have such constraints?

If you know that a type is not going to be an unmanaged type then don't let it implement the interface. Alternatively remove the constraint from the interface as it doesn't really make much sense. Just add the constraint to the implementation, to ensure that only unmanaged generic parameter types can be used for construction.


But I can't use IMyInterface as the generic type for MyField because it is not promised to be unmanaged

IMyInterface<T> is not only "not promised to be unmanaged" it is guaranteed to be managed due to boxing. When you are working with structs via interface they are boxed. Hence the following:
var x = new A<int>();
DoSomethingWithI(x);

void DoSomethingWithI(IMyInterface<int> p) => Console.WriteLine(p);

Results in the following IL:
IL_0000: ldloca.s 0
IL_0002: initobj valuetype A`1<int32>
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: box valuetype A`1<int32>
IL_000e: call void Program::'<<Main>$>g__DoSomethingWithI|0_0'(class IMyInterface`1<int32>)
IL_0013: ret

One way to workaround the problem is to use two generic paramters:
public struct Main<T, TVal> 
    where T : unmanaged, IMyInterface<TVal> 
    where TVal : unmanaged
{
    MyField<T> value;
    // ...
}

Though usage becomes a little bit clumsy:
var foo = new Main<A<int>, int>();

